# Incorporating capsicum oil into a chicken breading

Tags: chicken, breading

How can I incorporate capsicum oil into chicken breading?

Comment: I'd try adding it to the liquid.  But before I'd consider doing that, I'd use dried, crushed habañero in with the dry.

Comment: Capsicum oil? Something like that: http://www.amazon.com/Lee-Kum-Kee-Chili-Ounce/dp/B001NI726S/ or a very different product?

Comment: Usually, red oil is added after cooking. So I would first cook the meat, and then season it.

Comment: I actually read that as "chicken breeding".

Comment: @Joe this looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @TZDZ I can't ping two users in one comment, so here again separately: please say how you would do it in an answer, not in a comment.

Answer (score 3):

Breading chicken usually involves three stages:

1. Dip the chicken in flour to provide a uniform surface for egg to stick to
2. Dip it in an egg mixture
3. Dip it into bread crumbs or some other coarse, dry coating that will be the final texture.

Obviously the oil would not work in stages 1 or 3 because it could not be well distributed and would clump.

It is easy enough to add wet flavoring agents to the egg mixture. You should beat it well enough to partially emulsify the oil into the eggs so it doesn't all separate out on the first piece.

As Joe commented above, this seems like more trouble than it's worth. Mixing any kind of dried, ground or crushed peppers into the 3rd stage is much simpler. I use dried, crushed chipotles for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a long shot, but perhaps maltodextrin could be of service.

Maltodextrin is a type of complex sugar that reacts with oils to turn them into powders. This is frequently used in the food industry.

More info:http://www.modernistcookingmadeeasy.com/info/modernist-ingredients/more/maltodextrin-and-n-zorbit-m

Comment: Interesting idea - would the sweetness of the maltodextrun be an issue and where would you use the powder in the breading process? Welcome to Seasoned Advice!